# Kafka KTable Materialized-State-Store control

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ktable

We materialize the KTable into a Internal-State-Store.

a.) How and where can I specify that, this Internal-State-Store should be Persistent and be automatically backed-up to another kafka topic ?

b.) How can we specify that, this Internal-State-Store should be global one, so that any of my stream-task should be able to refer to that ?

c.) Is there a frequency, upon which the incoming messaageRecords are being written to the Internal-State-Store ? Can it happen that, a particular MessageRecord gets processed by Stream-processor, being stored in KTable, and then my stream-processor dies and it could not make entry to Internal-State-Store !!

Below snippet we use right now :-

```
KTable<String, String> KT0 = streamsBuilder.table(AppConfigs.topicName, Materialized.as(AppConfigs.stateStoreName)));
```

Any responses shall be highly appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

a) If you have a custom implementation of a state store, you can pass it via `Materialized.as(KeyValueStoreSupplier)`.

b) For global-store use-case, you can use `builder.globalKTable()`.

c) Writes happen on a per record basis, but could cached in-memory. Before input topic offsets are committed, the state store will be flushed though, and thus you will never miss any data. By default, KafkaStreams provides at-least-once processing semantics.

Comment: In my case, I use materialization of a KTable to a persistent state store, but I can't find any data (.sst files) in state.dir, only metadata

Comment: Hard to say. Maybe start a new question a provide more details what you exactly do, and how you run the app?

Comment: Yes I have already opened a question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77230575/missing-data-in-a-materialized-state-store-directory) if you can please have a look