# Missing data in a materialized state store directory

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My application does an aggregate on a *GroupedKTable*, which is then materialized to a *PersistentKeyValueStore*

I configured *state.dir* to a permanent path (not default */tmp/kstreams*)

I can see the key-values stored as events in the changelog-topic, and also my application succeeds to get them from the state store.

But when I go inspecting *state.dir* directory, I find only metadata there. No data (*.sst files* especially) are there (even if I am specifying a Persistent store)

Why is that so ? Where can I find the data ? It seems to me as a behavior of an InMemoryStore

The materialized looks like:

```scala
val StoreSupplier = Stores.persistentTimestampedKeyValueStore(name)
Materialized.as(StoreSupplier)(KeySerde, ValueSerde)
```

which then I pass to the aggregate.

Note: On local machine, with a TopologyTestDriver, I can see *.sst* files. My question applies to a real deployment of the application

Comment: What you do sounds correct -- how long did you let the application run? During a regular run, witch caching enabled (what is the default) flushes to local disk might be delayed. -- They should for sure happen when a commit happens thought (TTD "commits" after every record and flushes right away).

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I configured the StreamConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG to 0, and COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG to 10s, it didn't store the .sst file. However when I add an explicit store.flush() for testing purpose inside a transform method,  I see the .sst file. Any clue on any other missing configuration ?

Comment: Is it because of RocksDB different levels of storage (like memtable). Actually I am inserting few data, will data be flushed only after hitting some threshold ? I see the following in RocksDBStore.java : _long WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024 * 1024L;_

Comment: Well, on commit Kafka Streams calls `store.flush()` internally. -- The caching config you mentioned does not matter, because that's a Kafka Streams internal cache inside the JVM, ie, on top of RocksDB. -- Your commit interval is small, so after 10s Kafka Streams should do the `store.flush` and commit offsets afterwards. Can you confirm that offset are committed? -- If the flush is not happening, it would be a bug in Kafka Streams. What version are you using? Can you reproduce the issue with the latest version?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Actually I got it working. The reason was that data size didn't exceed one memtable size, so RocksDB didn't materialize it in sstables. Once I have around 20MB of data, a .sst file appears

Comment: Thanks for cycling back -- still wondering about this, because a `flush()` should actually force RocksDB to materialize even if memtable size is not reached? Or maybe I don't understand RocksDB well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

The initial answer I provided (below) is wrong.

The answer to the question is that Kafka-streams doesn't flush state stores at each commit (since  2.7.0).

There is an additional condition that should be satisfied so that the *flush* is triggered. The condition is that the delta between offsets in the changelog topic and the checkpoint file exceeds a threshold (currently 10.000 records !). When that is satisfied, both the new checkpoint is persisted and the flush is triggered.

For additional information check this jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9450

And source code in *AbstractTask.java*

```java
if (StateManagerUtil.checkpointNeeded(enforceCheckpoint, offsetSnapshotSinceLastFlush, offsetSnapshot)) {
            // the state's current offset would be used to checkpoint
            stateMgr.flush();
            stateMgr.checkpoint();
            offsetSnapshotSinceLastFlush = new HashMap<>(offsetSnapshot);
}
```

Recall that the checkpoint file stores the offset from changelog topic such that all the records before that offset are persisted on disk in the state store.

### Initial answer

This is actually a RocksDB detail.

When kafka-streams flushes data to RocksDB (either when *commit.interval.ms* is elapsed, or the cache is full), RocksDB stores data in an *active memtable*, as well as in a transaction log (which in kafka-streams is configured to be the changelog-topic).

Only when the memtable is full, which is configured to be 16MB in kafka-streams, the memtable becomes read-only, and at this moment it can be written to *.sst* files

As long as the size of store is less than memtable size, one cannot see *.sst* files in *state.dir*

I find the following article interesting to understand RocksDB details: https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-tune-rocksdb-kafka-streams-state-stores-performance/